# Is it possible to install TensorFlow using Anaconda 2.1 on Windows XP(32 bit)?

Tags: tensorflow, windows-xp, anaconda

I understand that initially TensorFlow did not work on Windows.
I have a Windows XP system with 2GB RAM and Anaconda 2.1 installed on it. Is there anyway to make TensorFlow work on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no official *pre-built* TensorFlow distribution that works on 32-bit Windows, and it is unlikely that we will ever support such an old operating system, because the versions of software that TensorFlow depends on (such as Python 3.5) do not support Windows XP.

The existing TensorFlow packages for Windows require a 64-bit installation of Python 3.5 (which may be Anaconda, or the Python.org distribution), and [Python 3.5 requires Windows Vista or newer](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html). Python on Windows [restricts what compilers may be used](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) to build extensions for each version of Python, and only Python 3.5 supports a new enough compiler (Visual C++ 14.0, from Visual Studio 2015) to build TensorFlow.